# Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Bool' to expected condition type 'Bool' and cannot find x in scope

Tags: swift

```
func patterns (list: Array<Int>, fn: (Int) -> Bool) -> Array<Int> {
var res =  Array<Int>()
for i in list {
    if fn {
        res.append(i)
    }
}
return res
}
let lst1 = [1, 2, 3 , 5 , 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10]
print(patterns(list: lst1, fn: x -> x % 2 == 0))
```

I am trying to write a function that takes a list and a closure function as an argument. I have wrtitten the above code. I want to print all the even number from lst1. I am getting these errors Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Bool' to expected condition type 'Bool' and cannot find x in scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors, see the fixes below.

```
import Foundation

func patterns (list: Array<Int>, fn: (Int) -> Bool) -> Array<Int> {
    var res =  Array<Int>()
    for i in list {
        if fn(i) { // Fix 1 is here
            res.append(i)
        }
    }
    return res
}
let lst1 = [1, 2, 3 , 5 , 6, 7, 8 ,9 , 10]
print(patterns(list: lst1, fn: { x in x % 2 == 0 })) // Fix 2 is here
```

You should read official docs on [Closures in Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) to learn more about this.

Comment: thank you do you have email address I want to ask you a question? @TarunTyagi

Comment: @CassandraTrotter You can ask the question here on SO.